# Make apple id from iphone - new region , no credit card

Tags: ios, apple-id, iphone

Okay - i know Apple say you must put in credit card info etc when you change region and try to log in -> sign up a new apple id. And i know there is no "None" option when you try to do this.

Now that we have settled that: - how is the work around this problem? How can i make a new apple id when i have changed region?

Virtual Visa Card? does this work? anyone have a guide? I have seen some pages having this service - but then i need to transfer money and that is not an option. Does anyone know about a "commen" fake credit card info i can put in?

Btw : i do this to get the pokemon app outside Austrailia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on where you create your apple id. If you create a new one its possible without a creditcard if you do it in iTunes.

Open iTunes, then go to the iTunes Store by clicking the iTunes Store button at the top of the window.

Scroll down and find the country flag in the lower-right corner of the window. If it's not the flag of the country where you live, click it and choose your country or region.

Go to the App Store, Music, TV Shows, or Books section of the store by clicking on one of the icons in the upper-left corner.

Download a **free** app, song, video, or book. To find free items, look in the right column of the window and click any link that includes the word "Free," such as "Free on iTunes" or "Top Free." When you find a free item, click Get beneath its icon.

When you're asked to sign in with an Apple ID, click Create Apple ID.

Follow the onscreen instructions. When you're asked for payment information, choose None as the payment type. [See what to do if None isn't showing or you can't select it.](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203905)

After you enter all of the information required, you'll be asked to verify your Apple ID by email. You must verify your Apple ID before you can begin using it.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204034

I just wish you wouldn't do it for Pokemon =)

Comment: Hmm i will try that! ;)
What would you see me rather do than pokemon? :-O

Svensk forresten?

Comment: How do you do this, if you can't find any free content in iTunes?  Now that the App store is separate, all the Movies and Songs in the region I'm interested in are paid only.